# Add childnode to xml doc

Tags: xml, winforms, appendchild

I am trying to search a XML file and if a certain dependency is not found, add that dependency to the end of the `<dependencies>`.
My XML File looks like this:

```
    <config>
      <settings>
      ...
      </settings>
<dependencies>
<dependency key="#0" type="Windows" name="Microsoft Windows XP" namepart="false"/>
    .
    .
    .
<dependancy key="#4" type="Windows" name="Microsoft Windows 7" namepart="false" />
</dependencies>
```

Now I would like to add a 5th dependency via code. (`<dependancy key="#5" type="Windows" name="Microsoft Windows NT" namepart="false" />`)
 How would I go about doing that. I have tried using XMLElement and appending it to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml Document is not orderd.
you can check for particular node , usualy using a key attribute.

```
    XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXMl(youxmlstring);
    XmlNode node=doc.SelectSingleNode("//dependancy/@name='Microsoft Windows NT'");
    if (node==null)
    {
            //no such node
            //insert new node
    }
```

To calculate new key attribute value you could use something like this

```
    //assuming key is currectly ordered
    int nextKey=doc.SelectNodes("//dependancy").Count;
```

see

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C